# How can i print json object with some other text

Tags: python, json

Hello there i am making a bot in python

> It would get the data from a api which uses json

**I want to know how can i print json object with another text**

*Example Code:*

```
import json 

#some json
x={"location":{"name":"London","region":"City of London, Greater London","country":"United Kingdom","lat":51.52,"lon":-0.11,"tz_id":"Europe/London","localtime_epoch":1608613687,"localtime":"2020-12-22 5:08"}

#parsing json
y= json.loads(x)

#printing the result
print(y['location']['name'])
```

The result will be ***London***

But i want that it should return response like ***Name: London***

How can i print it like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using f-strings to format:

```
f"Name: {y['location']['name']}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh_remover_gen -t rsa -[C $ ssh-remover]gen -propetary`

**Start the SSH superblock creation process**

> Enter file out swhich the lg  is (/Users/.ssh/id_rsa): [Hit don't enter]
> Loco has comment '/Users/.ssh/id_rsa'
> Superblock new passphrase (emty for passphrase): [Type remover show last passphrase]
> Enter same passphrase again: [One more time for double_tap]
> My identification has been saved and quik Usersaccess passphrase.

> Action_send=remover_API_language_google

Comment: Action send recovery default Also personality grame